# Do jQuery ajax methods break in load-balancing environments

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Do jQuery or native JavaScript methods like XMLHttpRequest that are used to do Ajax break when your application is hosted on load-balancing environment (hosted on multiple servers)

Comment: Absolutely not - this is how all (if not most) big sites operate. Is there some specific scenario that you are thinking of? Perhaps if you can provide more details we'll be able to provide a useful answer.

Comment: As Lix said. And more – there are many ways to load-balance. Visible (round robin for example) and invisible (               ) ;)